# Ошибка в my-app react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

При работе с CRA (даже в чистом my-app) в выдает ошибку: Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…               tc0.2,0,0.4-0.2,0…". В файле jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2. Чистил npm кэш, не помогло.

Comment: Не бывает `jquery` в CRA по умолчанию. Если же вы пытаетесь установить `jquery` в React, то это очень плохая идея

Comment: @EzioMercer почему плохая? Потом можно с лёгкостью удалить реакт и работать по-человечески 

Comment: EzioMercer ничего не устанавливал сам, чистое CRA, вот такая вот ошибка вылазит, не знаю почему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Эй! Мой реакт не трогать! Он - прекрасен❤️

Answer (score 0):

Это оказалось ошибкой хрома, сбросил настройки браузера и ошибка исчезла, всем спасибо.